# Slony-i replication on Postgre 9.3/slony 2.2.0/window 7

Tags: postgresql

Title : slony-i replication not working.

binary paths : `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share`

Master.txt

```
cluster name = testing;

node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=original host=localhost user=postgres password=sa';
node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=copy host=localhost user=postgres password=sa';

init cluster (id = 1,comment = 'Node 1 - Master');
create set (id = 1, origin = 1);

set add table (set id = 1,origin = 1,id = 1 , full qualified name = 'public.test');
store node(id = 2,event node = 1,comment = 'slave');

store path(server = 1,client = 2,conninfo = 'dbname=original host=localhost user=postgres password=sa');
store path(server = 2,client = 1,conninfo = 'dbname=copy host=localhost user=postgres password=sa');
```

Slave.txt

```
CLUSTER NAME = testing;

node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=original host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=sa';
node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=copy host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=sa';

subscribe set (id = 1,provider = 1, receiver = 2, forward = no);
```

error

[image: Error]

Question

keeping waiting for event and when i tested replication not working even slony replication appear.

thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a *slony* service on both master and slave machine.

create a file and name it slon.conf with content:

```
cluster_name=testing

conn_info = 'dbname = original host = localhost user = postgres password = sa port = 5432'
```

Then, go to command prompt and head to the postgres bin folder and type:

```
slon -regservice Slony-I

slon -addengine Slony-I slon.conf

slon -listengines Slony-I
```

This must be done in both Master and slave machine